# Locate up until quotes regex

Tags: c#, regex

Is it possible using regex on c# to locate a string `"http://www.foo.com/folder/file"` By only knowing the `"http://www.foo.com`.

So the steps would be:

- Locate `"http://www.foo.com`
- Then get all the rest of the string until reaching `"`

  ---

There are multiple `"http://www.foo.com/folder/file"` So I would like to be able to put them in a `string[]`

Comment: Is is possible to have escaped `"` in the strings? (e.g. `\"`)

Comment: I have this bit `"((?:\\.|[^"\\])*)"` but i dont know how to add the string `http://www.foo.com`

Comment: Sorry, I was called to change my laptop. That's already good. I'll put an answer in a few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
string regex = @"(http://www\.foo\.com(?:\\.|[^""\\])*)"
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/sZ1sK6)

Comment: You have to escape `"` with `""` to mean a single `"` when you use the literal string notation.

Comment: How do I then put each result in an array?

Comment: @Maximilian I'm not entirely familiar with it, but you can see a code sample [here](http://ideone.com/lwSaAX).

Comment: Hello I am getting an error when I replace the `string msg` with `webBrowser1.Document.Body.OuterHtml`

Comment: Dont worry sorted it!

Comment: @Maximilian You could perhaps break the loop as soon as you get the first result. Sorry if I'm not much of help here, I know the specifications of C# regexes, but I have yet to learn many of the basics of C# itself ^^;

Comment: No problem. Would you by any chance know how to write 2 more regex expressions?:

1) line containing: `<DD>` & `".jpg"`==>[`(@"(.jpg(?:\\.|[^""\\])*)"`]

2)`(` [number] `x` [number >720] `)`

Thank you

Comment: @Maximilian Sure. It would fit better as a new question though ;) Could you give an example string for each?

Comment: Do you want me to do it as a new question?

Comment: 1)`<DD><A href="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5212/5427155385_513b56bbcb_o_d.jpg">Download the Original size of this photo </A></DD></DL>`

Comment: 2) `(1818 x 701)` but not `(1818 x 700)`

Comment: @Maximilian It's okay for now. 1) Do you want to get `<DD><A href="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5212/5427155385_513b56bbcb_o_d.jpg`? 2) Shouldn't the first be `(1818 x 721)`?

Comment: 1)I want to get `"http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5212/5427155385_513b56bbcb_o_d.jpg"`

Comment: 2) what do you mean? I just want to check weather in the whole string there contains ([any number] x [a number greater than 720])

Comment: @Maximilian Something like [this](http://regex101.com/r/eZ7aS2) for 1)? For 2) You said above that the number is > 720, but 701 is not. Well, if it's really 720, then you can try [this](http://regex101.com/r/sU2gQ6).

Comment: Sorry To keep bothering you but can you turn those into c# capable regexs I have no idea how to!

Comment: @Maximilian You need to use `Group[1]` instead of `Group[0]` in the loop. `Group[0]` gives the whole match, `Group[1]` gives what's in the first pair of parentheses `()`. `Group[2]` gives what's in the second pair of `()` if there was one.

Comment: Thank you write that in as an answer on the other page and I will give you it!! Also what about this? sorry: `Regex rgx = new Regex("\(\d+ x (?:7(?:2[1-9]|[3-9]\d)|[8-9]\d{2}|\d{4,})\)");
            if (rgx.IsMatch(flick))
            {` This doesn't work?

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? Hmm, I put it in code [here](http://ideone.com/5PvnKQ).

Answer (score 1):

the following will get you the hyperlink without double quotes:

```
string regex = "http://www\\.foo\\.com[^\"]*"
```

the string is updated. the . should be escaped.

Comment: How can I view the equiv on here http://regexpal.com/ ? sorry I am a newbie to regex